# Integration of Time series model of R in Tableau

Tags: r, tableau-api

I am trying to integrate Time series Model of R in Tableau and I am new to integration. Please help me in resolving below mentioned Error. Below is my code in tableau for integration with R. Calculation is Valid bur getting an error.

```
SCRIPT_REAL(
   "library(forecast);
   cln_count_ts <- ts(.arg1,frequency = 7);
   arima.fit <- auto.arima(log10(cln_count_ts));
   forecast_ts <- forecast(arima.fit, h =10);",
   SUM([Count]))
```

Error : Error in auto.arima(log10(cln_count_ts)) : No suitable ARIMA model found

Comment: As it is without a reproducible example, please check the code by running it outside the tableau using the same dataset

Comment: @akrun are you asking me to run the same code in R environment ?

Comment: It is to check whether the `.arg1` works correctly outside or not.  For e.g. if I do `set.seed(24)'
 cln_count_ts <- ts(rnorm(150), frequency = 7);
  arima.fit <- auto.arima(log10(cln_count_ts));forecast_ts <- forecast(arima.fit, h =10);`  it works without any error.  So, you have to check the data that is used

Comment: @akrun I have tried below code and it has worked. I have used .arg1 in tableau as tableau doesn't take "Count" as variable. That is the reason I have taken .arg1 and I have defined .arg1 at the end. sum([count])
cln_count_ts <- ts(data_ts$COUNT,frequency = 7)
arima.fit <- auto.arima(log10(cln_count_ts))
forecast_ts <- forecast(arima.fit, h =10)

Comment: @akrun I have tried below code and it has worked. I have used .arg1 in tableau as tableau doesn't take "Count" as variable. That is the reason I have taken .arg1 and I have defined .arg1 at the end as sum([count]).
  

cln_count_ts <- ts(data_ts$COUNT,frequency = 7) arima.fit <- auto.arima(log10(cln_count_ts)) forecast_ts <- forecast(arima.fit, h =10)

Answer (score 2):

When Tableau calls R, Python, or another tool, it does so as a "table calc". That means it sends the external system one or more **vectors** as arguments and expects a single vector in response.

Depending on your data and calculation, you may want to send all your data to R in a single call, passing a very large vector, or call it several times with different vectors - say forecasting each region separately. Or even call R multiple times with many vectors of size one (aka scalars).

So with table calcs, you have other decisions to make beyond just choosing the function to invoke. Chiefly, you have to decide how to partition your data for analysis. And in some cases, you also need to determine the order that the data appears in the vectors you send to R - say if the order implies a time series.

The Tableau terms for specifying how to divide and order data for table calculations are "partitioning and addressing". See the section on that topic in the online help. You can change those settings by using the "Edit Table Calc" menu item.